# How to convert records in a table to xml format in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I fetched some records from a table named a2h_member in php. i want to convert it into XML format. How can i do this?. Give me some suggestions or code. Please Help me

Answer (score 2):

The simpler the better:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><result>';

foreach($result as $row){
 $xml .= '<row>';
 foreach($row as $key=>$value){
   $xml .= "<{$key}><![CDATA[{$value}]]></{$key}>";
 }
 $xml .= '</row>';
}
$xml .= '</result>';
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using magic quotes here. Magic quotes are discouraged and soon to be deprecated. Just do the explicit string concatenation.

Comment: @Jonathan Fingland: This code doesn't use magic quotes, it uses variable expansion, which I don't expect ever to be deprecated. Variable expansion in double-quoted strings: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing; Magic quotes: http://uk3.php.net/magic_quotes